# Como limpiar messages.success que se repite al mostrarlo en el navegador

Tags: python, django, django-views

Cada ves que reproduzco el error me genera una lista de mensajes y si es exitoso me muestra los errores mas el mensaje exitoso. Como puedo controlar esto?

view.py

```
class CargaMasivaEmpleadosView(FormView):
    form_class = CargarMasivaEmpleadosForm

    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        importador_empleados = ImportEmpleados()
        filename = handle_uploaded_file(self.request.FILES['file'])
        no_cargados = importador_empleados.importar_formulario(filename)
        if not len(no_cargados):
            messages.success(self.request, 'El archivo fue cargado exitosamente')
        else:
            for no_cargado in no_cargados:
                messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR, no_cargado, extra_tags='is-danger')
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

template.html

```
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="notification {{ message.tags }}">
                {{ message }}<br>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Imagen 1
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen 2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me se añade uno mas cada que reproduzco ese u otro mensaje que notifique el estado.

Agradezco a quien me pueda indicar como puedo limpiar ese contenido?

Comment: Te aparecen tantos mensajes, porque estas añadiendo los mensajes dentro de un bucle `for`.

Comment: Si, me acabo de dar cuenta que tengo una lista en el importador que almacena los errores y no la estoy reiniciando.

Comment: Ok, y ahora tienes un error o inconveniente?

Comment: No, ya esta funcionando bien

Comment: Ok, saludos!! :)